# redirigir mediante un checkbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Necesito colocar un checkbox en mi formulario de rails que cuando este este checado y el usuario guarde el formulario, se le redirija a otra pagina, pero solo cuando dicho checkbox este checado y este es un campo que no estará en la base de datos. como podría hacerlo? había pensado en algo como esto:

```
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Utiliza Envase:</label>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id='showAreaBox' class="producto_Utl.Env">
              </div>
```

y en el create.js.erb:

```
$('#showAreaBox').change(function() {

    // if the checkbox is checked, invoke the link
    if(this.checked ) {
      $(window.location.replace("/Productos/<%= @producto.id %>/envase"))

    }

    // checkbox is unchecked
    // else {}
});
```

el controlador:

```
class ProductosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_producto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_usuario!

  # GET /productos
  # GET /productos.json
  def index
    @productos = Producto.activos.por_empresa(current_usuario.empresa_id)
    @producto = Producto.new


  end



  # GET /productos/1
  # GET /productos/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /productos/new
  def new
    @producto = Producto.new

  end

  # GET /productos/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /productos
  # POST /productos.json
  def create
    @producto = Producto.new(producto_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @producto.save
        format.html { redirect_to @producto, notice: 'Producto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @producto }
        format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'El producto se ha creado de forma exitosa.'} #ajax

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @producto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js {flash.now[:alert] = 'Error al crear el producto.'} #ajax

      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /productos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /productos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @producto.update(producto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @producto, notice: 'Producto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @producto }
        format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'El producto se ha actualizado de forma exitosa.'} #ajax

      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @producto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js {flash.now[:alert] = 'Error al actualizar el producto.'} #ajax

      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /productos/1
  # DELETE /productos/1.json
  def destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to productos_url, notice: 'Producto was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }

        format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'El producto se ha borrado de forma exitosa.'} #ajax
      end

    end
  end



  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_producto
      @producto = Producto.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def producto_params
      params.require(:producto).permit(:Clave, :Producto, :CodBarras)
    end
end
```

Comment: No necesitas JavaScript para esto si vas a enviar el formulario. Esto, lo deberás de manejar desde el controlador según los parámetros que recibes del formulario.
Podrías poner tu controlador?

Comment: @hcarreras listo ya coloque el controlador, pero de que forma podría hacerlo? debido a que dicho checkbox no se estará guardando en la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no necesitas guardar nada en la base de datos. Un formulario enviará una petición al servidor (tu aplicación Rails) con la información que tu quieras. Esta petición la va a gestionar tu controlador (controller). Lo que decidas hacer con esta información dependerá del código del controlador. En otras palabras, el modelo y el controlador son independientes.

En este caso, tu formulario debe de tener un atributo 'name' para que sea su valor sea incluido en la petición del formulario. Podría ser algo así:

```
label class="control-label col-md-3">Utiliza Envase:</label>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="checkbox" id='showAreaBox' name='envase' class="producto_Utl.Env">
          </div>
```

Fíjate que le he añadido el campo 'name' con 'envase'
Ahora, cuando envies los datos de tu formulario, el controlador lo recibirá como un parámetro que puedes controlar desde params.

Por ello, en tu controlador podrías hacer algo así:

```
def create
  @producto = Producto.new(producto_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @producto.save
      if params[:envase]
        #Responde aquí con lo que quieras, por ejemplo:
        format.html { redirect_to envase_path, notice: 'Ha seleccionado envase.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @producto, notice: 'Producto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @producto }
        format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'El producto se ha creado de forma exitosa.'} #ajax
      end
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @producto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js {flash.now[:alert] = 'Error al crear el producto.'} #ajax
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: excelente amigo, muchísimas gracias, había estado rompiéndome el coco con eso y no sabia de que forma hacerlo, además de eso muy bien explicado, no sabia que necesitaba del atributo name en este caso para que pueda ser recibido por el controller. GRACIAS, al final me quedo de esta forma para redirigir a otra pagina: if params[:envase]
          format.js {render :js => "window.location.href='"+producto_envase_path(@producto)+"'"}
        end